# Oracle SQL - Query 2 tables based on their foreign keys

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables and i want to make a single query and group them based on their foreign key. Here's an example :

Departments

```
DEPART_ID(PK) - DEPART_NAME

   1          - Accounting
   2          -    IT
```

Employees

```
EMP_ID(PK) - NAME - SURNAME - DEPART_ID(FK)

  1        - John   - John   -    1
  2        - George - George -    2
```

Managers

```
MANAG_ID(PK) - NAME    - SURNAME   - DEPART_ID(FK)
     1       - Nick    - Nick      -     1
     2       - Michael - Michael   -     2
```

And i want to get this output grouped by their department name.

```
Accounting      |       IT 
----------------|-------------------
John John       |   George George
Nick Nick       |   Michael Michael
```

I've tried but i can't make it to work. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want to group by department, but the output you show puts George George in the accounting column when he's in the IT department in the table and Nick nick is shown in the IT column when he is in the Accounting department in the table.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: yes you are right ! the output is correct now !

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by using this:

```
select *  from
(select name || ' ' || Surname Accounting from employees where depart_id = 1),
(select name || ' ' || Surname  IT from employees where depart_id =2)
union
select * from
(select name || ' ' || Surname Accounting from managers where depart_id = 1),
(select name || ' ' || Surname  IT from managers where depart_id =2)
```

Comment: Because this was an example and i have more than "accounting" and "IT" is there a more simple query? i have 4 departments to be exact.

Comment: This is a simple as it gets, you either add a subquery for each department to extract the data from each table (a potential maintenance issue depending on your context) or you write a PL/Sql procedure to manipulate the data based upon the data in the departments table.

Comment: actually yes the query works fine but all are duplicates in the output. How do you fix that?

Comment: `UNION` by default eliminates duplicate rows.

Comment: I know but if i have for example 2 employees on DEPART_ID = 1 it shows everyone 2 times..

Comment: And to be exact if i insert a third SELECT it runs every SELECT 3 times

Comment: Yes, it would.  Unless you have the exact number of rows in the manager and employee tables the query will return a manager row for each employee row or a employee row for each manager row, depends on what table has the most rows.  I don't believe the result set you want is possible with a single query.  You would need to create an alias using the data in the departments table so that the columns in the resultset have those names.  You can do that in a PL/Sql procedure building a string of the query or queries you need and using execute immediate.

Comment: So i must change my table structure completely?

Comment: Not if you use a procedure.  I don't know the context of what you're doing, so it's hard to say what you need to do.  With the given question, the resultset needs to have a column for each department in departments table and an entry in each column for each row in the employees table and manager table.  Ignoring the impact of a specific context, perhaps what you would want to do is group employees by manager within department.  Again, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. The sub-query formats the name and generates a join key for employees within department. The main query splits the WITH output into sub-queries based on `depart_id` which are joined on the generated key; the full outer join allows for departments to have different numbers of people.

```
with emps as
    ( select depart_id, 
             name || ' ' || Surname  ename ,
             row_number() over (partition by depart_id order by emp_id) rn
      from employees)
select acct.ename as accounting
       , it.ename as IT
       , sal.ename as sales
       , hr.ename as hr
from (select * from emps where department_id = 1) acct
     full outer join (select * from emps where department_id = 2) it
     on acct.rn = it.rn 
     full outer join (select * from emps where department_id = 3)  sal
     on acct.rn = sal.rn 
     full outer join (select * from emps where department_id = 4)  hr
     on acct.rn = hr.rn 
order by acct.rn, it.rn, sal.rn, hr.rn
/
```